# Nextcloud automatic user add

Tags: bash, ubuntu, nextcloud

I am trying to write a script that takes data from a MariaDB table and creates a user in my hosted Nextcloud server. When I execute the script, it says "username added to nextcloud" but I when I pull up Nextcloud in my browser, no new users are created... Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_HOST="localhost"
DB_NAME="UsersNextcloud"
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASS=""

NC_DIR="/var/www/nextcloud"

USER_DETAILS=$(mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -h $DB_HOST $DB_NAME -e "SELECT Username, Display_Name, Password FROM Connect WHERE Display_Name ='WillN';" --skip-column-names)

if [ -z "$USER_DETAILS" ]; then
    echo "No users to add."
    exit 0
fi

USERNAME=$(echo "$USER_DETAILS" | awk '{print $1}')
DISPLAYNAME=$(echo "$USER_DETAILS" | awk '{print $2}')
HASHED_PASSWORD=$(echo "$USER_DETAILS" | awk '{print $3}')


sudo -u www-data php $NC_DIR/occ user:add --display-name="$DISPLAYNAME" --group="Users" --password-from-env "$USERNAME" >& /dev/null <<EOF
$(echo $HASHED_PASSWORD | sed 's/\\$/\\\\$/g')
EOF

echo "Added user $USERNAME to Nextcloud."

exit 0
```

The mariadb table I made is called Connect by the way, which is the table I am trying to retrieve data from.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I would expect nextcloud to clean the internal user table of invalid entries. And I doubt that just entering a line into that table is enough to create a valid user. Why don't you use the `occ` executable instead which offers exactly such functionality?